# Calculating Solar Requirements for a Refrigerator

Tags: solar-cell, power-consumption

I am attempting to run a refrigerator on solar power, it's "Energy Guide" says 410 kWh/year, so I assumed that it uses 46 W each hour (410 kWh / number of hours per year = 410 kWh / 8760 = 46 W), I really double that a refrigerator would require that very low power, or this is the running power?

The power consumed while the motor is running? and not starting?

Since I have seen that the power required to start the refrigerator is 10x that, so 460 watt required from my solar panel to run this fridge?

Comment: Solar heat transfer fluid to an Ammonia refrigerator.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you may be confusing *energy* with *power*, resulting in some comparisons that don't make sense.

A refrigerator has a (hopefully) low duty cycle, meaning that it's actively cooling down only a small part of the time. Based on the Energy Guide numbers, that means that it's using about 1.12 kWh each day. As you calculated, that is an average of 46 Watts. However, this is an average over a long period of time (a year!), with many on/off cycles. This "average" is useful for figuring out how much solar energy you need to generate (and store) in a day to break even.

Depending on the size of the refrigerator, efficiency, etc... the refrigerator may draw hundreds or thousands of watts when it's running, and close to zero when it is "resting". All appliances should say the maximum current they draw from the outlet - this is the instantaneous power. You would use this value to figure out how large of an AC inverter you need.

Comment: so maximum instantaneous power in amperes? i convert that to watt using Ampere * Operating Volt * 0.8 ?

Comment: @user41468 Current*voltage is power. In practice, you will see a lower power draw because that value is usually  conservative.

Comment: what about "Hard Start Relay Capacitor" will this be of any help to me? i think it reduces starting current, correct?\

Comment: @user41468 It's unlikely that you will be able to effectively change the start-up current of the motor, or the continuous current while it is running.

Comment: not even reduce it?

Comment: @user41468 A refrigerator performs work - it moves heat from inside the cabinet to the outside. You aren't going to be able to cheat that to a lower value. If you lower the current to the motor, it can't work as well, resulting in longer run times and more energy consumed.

Comment: more energy consumed yes, but less solar requirements, less panels and lower voltage controller, correct? i mean, 400 watts start, then running on 45 watts for 10 minutes is better than 700 watts start and 45 watts for 2 minutes, for me at least.

Comment: @user41468 The 45 Watt figure is *continuous/average* power draw *including when the compressor isn't running* - it's what you have to budget for with your solar panels and batteries. A motor-start capacitor is on for less than a second and will not really change your real power ratings for your inverter.

Answer (score 1):

Well the "Energy Guide" and you both are correct. To know why you must understand the operation of refrigerator.

First the refrigerator is at room temperature. When you switch it on, then it starts cooling. So at that time it consumes maximum power. You should really find the power consumption at this point. You can use a simple [Power Meter](http://www.ebay.com/itm/plug-AC-110-220v-Digital-Voltage-power-meter-monitor-watt-KWh-time-Volt-Ammeter-/261210374944) to do that. This stage is considered as **Start up state**.

Now when your refrigerator is cooled down below pre-set temperature, the refrigeration process stops. At this point the power consumed is lowest. This can be termed as **Ideal state**. When the temperature inside the refrigerator increases above pre-defined value, the compressor starts again to initiate cooling process. But at this time it consumes more power than **ideal state** and less power than **start up state**.

So finally when you take the average power consumption over a year, you get a value far less than that required at the Start up state.

Comment: so in my calculations, should i use multiplier like 10x to calculate? 460w?

Comment: Yes. But you can get a more accurate value if you actually heat your refrigerator to room temp. by switching it off. Then measuring the actual wattage consumed during its cooling process.

Answer (score 0):

If it's got an 'Energy Guide', then probably there would be some sort of electrical specifications sticker with the rated power consumption as well. Now this rated power again would be at a certain temperature, according to the local standards, of the condenser (which is sometimes outside and sometimes inside the refrigerator). This can either be scaled up based on a judgement of the 'worst-case' condenser temperature or can be actually measured (by operating the appliance at higher outside temperatures).

The solar panels and intermediate storage can then be sized accordingly for power. The cables would need to be sized according to the current draw considering the (lower?) voltage of the panels.

Answer (score 0):

I am installing a solar system and have purchased a new refrigerator rated at 408 KWh/year.  I looked at the tag on the compressor and saw that LRA is just under 12.
LRA stands for Locked Rotor Amps and that is the maximum current that the compressor would ever draw.  So the INVERTER has to deliver 12x120 or 1440 Watts, peak, for a fraction of a second.  Add a bit for losses along the way.  That is frig only, so if something else is using power at the same time that has to be considered. What short-term power can your inverter deliver?

I then put an ammeter on the frig wire and found that it uses .8 to 1 amps while running (not in defrost cycle), so about 120 watts.  That is surprisingly low, to me at least.  And the compressor only runs for a fraction of the time, depending on how often you open the door.

The 408 KWh per year works out to 1.12 KWh per day.  I don't care about hours, since the sun doesn't shine at night and varies considerably during the day.  So my batteries have to supply 1.12KWh to the frig in a day, and the panels have to recharge them by that amount.  Of course the batteries should only be discharged about 20% if you expect a reasonable life-span, and you have to expect some days without sun.  So I've multiplied by 10 (20% discharge and 2 days without sun) so am planning on batteries rated for 12 KWh.  For a 12 volt system that is 1000 Ah (12000 Wh/12 V).  So 2 batteries at 6 volts and 500 Ah will do the trick.  Battery specs tell you how many Ah the battery can deliver at a certain rate.  With my system the current draw will average about 4 Amps so I am using the 50 Hr rate.  That means a battery labelled at 550 Ah will easily deliver 500 Ah at the 50 Hr rate.  (I get the 4 amps by dividing 1.12 KWh/day by 24 h, so 50 Watthrs/hr, then dividing by 120 volts, so .41amphrs per hour at 120 volts, then multiply by 10 v to get amps at 12 volts.  That comes to 4 amps.)

The panels then have to recharge the batteries - I would say in a day.  I won't do those numbers here.

Comment: You said for your 12v 1000Ah battery bank you will need two 6v 500Ah batteries? Will that still not remain 500Ah as the two 6v batteries will be connected in series? Wont you need 4 x 500Ah?